# What does the Ruby SecurityError 'Insecure operation: -r (SecurityError)' mean?

Tags: ruby

Executing

```
ruby -e 'Thread.new {$SAFE=3; File.read "/tmp/foo"}.join'
```

results in

```
-e:1:in `read': Insecure operation: -r (SecurityError)
from -e:1:in `block in <main>'
```

Why? What does the `-r` signify? Googling I only found [this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/884) old Redmine issue, which seems to indicate it was 'fixed'. Replace `File.read` by `load` or similar 'insecure' operations doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-r` means `read`.

Safe level 3 means, that no external resources are allowed - program is not allowed to read any data from objects created after setting $SAFE to 3. It means you can't do

```
 Thread.new {$SAFE=3; File.read "/tmp/foo"}.join
```

but you are allowed to do:

```
Thread.new {file = File.open "/tmp/foo"; $SAFE=3; file.read}.join
```

Similarly you should't have any troubles with reading from STDIN, as it was declared earlier. Level 4 disables using any IO objects. More details: http://ruby.about.com/od/qa/ss/What-Are-Taint-And-Trust.htm

Comment: The messages of most security errors are pretty clear in what is wrong. Do you happen to know why this is one is so much more opaque?